# How to retrieval vertex set from 3D coordinate edge set

Tags: python, 3d, coordinates

I have list of edges in 3D as following
((x1, y1, z1), (x2,y2,z2))
.....
((x_k, y_k, z_k), (x_t, y_t, z_t))

From them, I need obtain list of vertex.

My current idea:
Create initial emty set V

Check all edges, check coordinate of 2 points, if it is not in set V, add it to V.

I feel it is not fast when checking one by one whether 3D coordinate exist in set or not.

I need a cleaner and faster method? Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Since all edges consist of vertices, you need just extract all vertices and drop duplicated ones, e.g.

```
>>> x = [((1,2), (1,5)), ((2,3), (4,5)), ((1, 2), (6,7))]
>>> set(sum(x, tuple()))
{(1, 2), (1, 5), (4, 5), (2, 3), (6, 7)}
```

or

```
>>> list(set(sum(x, tuple())))
```

Comment: Woww. Thank alot, can you explain sum(x, tuple())

Comment: If you look at docstring of `sum` function, you can see that it has `default` as a second variable. It is initial value to accumulate the sum, e.g. `sum([1,2,3], 10) = 16` =  10 + 1+ 2+ 3 (summation starts at 10 - initial value); In case of tuples we can also define such default value: `sum([((1, 2), (3, 4)), ((7,8), ) ], tuple()) = ((1, 2), (3, 4)) + ((7,8),) + tuple()` => flattens a list of nested tuples.